# Python using bar_label on multiple bars

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, bar-chart

I would like to use the offer_difference list as bar_label on the plot. Prefer one that's in the above the two bars in the middle. However, after reading many explanations and tutorials including the official matplotlib ones, I can't manage to do it.

Example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

name = ['Jay', 'Bert', 'Mike', 'Aaron']
name_len = np.arange(len(name))
best_offer = [0.21, 0.34, 0.6, 0.8]
best_offer_est = [0.25, 0.4, 0.5, 0.75]
offer_difference = [16, 15, -20, -6.6]

f = plt.figure()
f.set_figwidth(20)
f.set_figheight(10)
plt.bar(name_len - 0.2, best_offer, 0.4, label = 'Best Offer')
plt.bar(name_len + 0.2, best_offer_est, 0.4, label = 'Best Offer Est', edgecolor = 'gray', linewidth = 4)
plt.xticks(name_len, name, rotation = 45, ha = 'right', label = offer_difference)
plt.legend()
```

Please give me a little explanation how to solve it issue. I am certainly interested :)

Answer (score 0):

A method you can use is adding a `text` for the first bar of each pair and move it into position. To do this you can use the `BarContainer` that `plt.bar` returns (rects1 and rects2 in my code below) and get the x and y locations to use as guidance for the `text`. Here is how you can go about it:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


if __name__ == '__main__':

    name = ['Jay', 'Bert', 'Mike', 'Aaron']
    name_len = np.arange(len(name))
    best_offer = [0.21, 0.34, 0.6, 0.8]
    best_offer_est = [0.25, 0.4, 0.5, 0.75]
    offer_difference = [16, 15, -20, -6.6]

    f = plt.figure()
    f.set_figwidth(20)
    f.set_figheight(10)
    rects1 = plt.bar(name_len - 0.2, best_offer, 0.4, label='Best Offer')
    rects2 = plt.bar(name_len + 0.2, best_offer_est, 0.4, label='Best Offer Est', edgecolor='gray', linewidth=4)
    plt.xticks(name_len, name, rotation=45, ha='right', label=offer_difference)
    plt.legend()

    # Add offer difference labels above bars
    for idx_rect, rect in enumerate(rects1):
        # Get x location and put the label in between the two bars
        xloc = rect.get_x() + 0.3
        # Get y location for bar 1
        yloc1 = rect.get_y() + rect.get_height()
        # Compare with bar 2 height
        yloc2 = rects2[idx_rect].get_y() + rects2[idx_rect].get_height()
        # Use the heighest y value between bar1 and bar2 - that way the label is above both bars
        yloc = np.max([yloc1, yloc2]) + 0.03
        # Add label
        plt.text(xloc, yloc, offer_difference[idx_rect], va='center', color='k', rotation=0)

    plt.ylim([0, 0.9])
    plt.show()
```

[image: fig bars with labels]